# What is the purpose of comparing CMP AL, 1 in this code?

Tags: assembly, x86

```
    SUBTTL IOFUNC -- DO FUNCTION 1-12 I/O
    PAGE
    IOFUNC_RETRY:
    ASSUME  DS:NOTHING,ES:NOTHING
    invoke  restore_world

    procedure   IOFUNC,NEAR
    ASSUME  DS:NOTHING,ES:NOTHING

    ; Inputs:
    ;       DS:SI Points to FCB
    ;       AH is function code
    ;               = 0 Input
    ;               = 1 Input Status
    ;               = 2 Output
    ;               = 3 Output Status
    ;               = 4 Flush
    ;       AL = character if output
    ; Function:
    ;       Perform indicated I/O to device or file
    ; Outputs:
    ;       AL is character if input
    ;       If a status call
    ;               zero set if not ready
    ;               zero reset if ready (character in AL for input status)
    ; For regular files:
    ;       Input Status
    ;               Gets character but restores fcb_RR field
    ;               Zero set on EOF
    ;       Input
    ;               Gets character advances fcb_RR field
    ;               Returns ^Z on EOF
    ;       Output Status
    ;               Always ready
    ; AX altered, all other registers preserved

    MOV     WORD PTR [IOXAD+2],SS
    MOV     WORD PTR [IOXAD],OFFSET DOSGROUP:DEVIOBUF
    MOV     WORD PTR [IOSCNT],1
    MOV     WORD PTR [DEVIOBUF],AX

    IOFUNC2:
    TEST    [SI.fcb_DEVID],080H
    JNZ     IOTODEV
    JMP     IOTOFILE

    IOTODEV:
    invoke  save_world
    PUSH    DS
    PUSH    SS
    POP     ES
    PUSH    SS
    POP     DS
    ASSUME  DS:DOSGROUP
    XOR     BX,BX
    MOV     [IOCALL.REQSTAT],BX
    MOV     BYTE PTR [IOMED],BL

    MOV     BX,OFFSET DOSGROUP:IOCALL

    MOV     CX,(DEVRD SHL 8) OR DRDWRHL
    OR      AH,AH
    JZ      DCALLR
    MOV     CX,(DEVRDND SHL 8) OR DRDNDHL
    DEC     AH
    JZ      DCALLR
    MOV     CX,(DEVWRT SHL 8) OR DRDWRHL
    DEC     AH
    JZ      DCALLO
    MOV     CX,(DEVOST SHL 8) OR DSTATHL
    DEC     AH
    JZ      DCALLO
    DFLUSH:
    MOV     CX,(DEVIFL SHL 8) OR DFLSHL
    DCALLR:
    MOV     AH,86H
    DCALL:
    MOV     [IOCALL.REQLEN],CL
    MOV     [IOCALL.REQFUNC],CH
    MOV     CL,AH
    POP     DS
    ASSUME  DS:NOTHING
    CALL    DEVIOCALL
    MOV     DI,[IOCALL.REQSTAT]
    TEST    DI,STERR
    JZ      OKDEVIO
    MOV     AH,CL
    invoke  CHARHARD
    CMP     AL,1   // **this is my trouble**
    JZ      IOFUNC_RETRY
    ;Know user must have wanted ignore. Make sure device shows ready so
    ;that DOS doesn't get caught in a status loop when user simply wants
    ;to ignore the error.
    AND     BYTE PTR [IOCALL.REQSTAT+1], NOT (STBUI SHR 8)
    OKDEVIO: continues.........
```

I am still unable to find that, what is the purpose of comparing AL with "1" in (CMP AL,1) instruction? I have gone through the procedure CHARHARD, but still couldn't understand.

I am working on a project on MS DOS programming.

```
SUBTTL CHARHRD,HARDERR,ERROR -- HANDLE DISK 
ERRORS AND RETURN TO USER
PAGE
    procedure   CHARHARD,NEAR
ASSUME  DS:NOTHING,ES:NOTHING,SS:DOSGROUP

; Character device error handler
; Same function as HARDERR

    MOV     WORD PTR [EXITHOLD+2],ES
    MOV     WORD PTR [EXITHOLD],BP
    PUSH    SI
    AND     DI,STECODE
    MOV     BP,DS                   ;Device pointer is BP:SI
    CALL    FATALC
    POP     SI
    return
CHARHARD    ENDP
```

Here is the FATALC code:

```
    FATALC:
    CMP     BYTE PTR [ERRORMODE],0
    JNZ     SETIGN                  ; No INT 24s if already INT 24
    MOV     [CONTSTK],SP
    PUSH    SS
    POP     ES
    ASSUME  ES:DOSGROUP
    CLI                             ; Prepare to play with stack
    INC     BYTE PTR [ERRORMODE]    ; Flag INT 24 in.    
    progress
    DEC     BYTE PTR [INDOS]        ; INT 24 handler might.      
    not return
    MOV     SS,[user_SS]
    ASSUME  SS:NOTHING
    MOV     SP,ES:[user_SP]         ; User stack pointer.     
    restored
    INT     int_fatal_abort         ; Fatal error interrupt vector, 
    must preserve ES
    MOV     ES:[user_SP],SP         ; restore our stack
    MOV     ES:[user_SS],SS
    MOV     SP,ES
    MOV     SS,SP
    ASSUME  SS:DOSGROUP
    MOV     SP,[CONTSTK]
    INC     BYTE PTR [INDOS]        ; Back in the DOS
    MOV     BYTE PTR [ERRORMODE],0  ; Back from INT 24
    STI
```

Comment: Presumably a status code is returned in `al` signalling whether it's a retryable error (since `jz IOFUNC_RETRY`). It is probably set by `FATALC` or some subroutine thereof. You did not show that code.

Comment: That's getting closer. Notice how it does `INT int_fatal_abort` (aka. `int 24h`). If you consult the documentation you can see that in fact returns a status code.

Comment: Did you read the comments?  They explain why the comparison is happening.

Answer (score 2):

Presuming the macro ‘invoke’ isn’t really weird, it is effectively checking the return value of FATALC; so if FATALC returns with AL equal to 1 it will invoke IOFUNC_RETRY otherwise it will continue into that other weird code.....

If you don’t mind my asking:  It is 2018.  Why are you learning to program in MS-DOS?   Are you involved in time travel?

Comment: Dear, I agree that this is old code, But I am included in a project concerning MSDOS source code programming. So that we may understand basic programming for device/file input/output.